# implementing Minimum-Heap with LinkedList in Java

Tags: linked-list, computer-science, heap

I've got a task to implement a Minimum-Heap with linked list data structure.
I am a bit struggling with the structure of the program and will be glad for help.

My idea is to create a class called node with left son, right son, and parent.
create NodesLinkedList class extends Java's LinkedList so instead of storing elements, the LinkedList will store node objects.
Also in the NodesLinkedList class create methods like extract-minimum,minimum,insert like an actual heap.

do you think it's the right approach? am I missing here something?

Comment: I'm not sure that essentially creating all the nodes of a tree-based heap complete with parent and child pointers and then putting those nodes into a list is really different from implementing the heap as a Tree. It sounds like a Tree which just happens to also have its nodes stored in a list, which might not be what they're going for.

Comment: It would be possible to use a linked list to mimic an array-based implementation, which encodes parent/child relationships and the heap structure purely by the order values appear in the list. The values of the heap would appear in the list ordered first by level, then left to right. In this way, a node at index i would have its children at 2i + 1 and 2i + 2, so you can move between parents/children/siblings by just walking up and down the list and keeping track of what index you're at and implement heap operations accordingly. That might be more what they're looking for.

Comment: But your general idea about extending the LinkedList class sounds right

Comment: Are you sure you're accurately describing the problem.  A LinkedList is perhaps the worst data structure for implementing a minHeap.  I've never seen an implementation using anything other than an array or Vector.